# Excel Criteria for cell

Tags: excel, vba

Cell A1 can contain a value between 1 - 5
    Cell B1 can contain a value between 1 - 5
    Cell C1 is the value in A1 * B1
    Cell D1: if value in C1 is 1 or <=10, then the cell colour is green
    Cell D1: if val in C1 is =>11 and =< 16 then the cell color is amber
    Cell D1: if val in C1 is =>17 and =< 25 then the cell color is red

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Nope...what is your question?  Where is your code?

Comment: @Eddie Aldridge you realy don't need VBA for this, straight forward Excel, formulas and Conditional Formatting is all you need

Answer (score 0):

You either need [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) if you want to enforce value restrictions, or [Conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) if you want to change the format of cells based on conditions.

Or both, if you need both.